# The reason for selling not profitable Antminer through official channel

Tags: asics

I am a total newbie into ETH mining, so I may be asking about something obvious.

I have found [this Bitmine website](https://shop.bitmain.com/product/detail?pid=00020220718220503782cMK0083505EE) where it says that Miner E9 is sold out, but will return to sell in a couple of months:

> Shipping Date: 15-31,Oct.2022

Then I found this [two years old Qurora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-lifetime-of-Antminer-S9-or-some-other-ASIC-processors) which says that two years ago Miner E9 was already not profitable:

> Antminer s9 is going to obsolete soon. Or you can consider it obsolete from now on…

What am I missing? What is the reason for bringing back to sell a gear that was obsolete two years ago? What is the reason for selling 10k USD Antminer that will never be profitable again?

Comment: I would worry too much now about mining ETH, because Ethereum 2.0 POS merge is coming, probably next month or in a couple of months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never know for sure what will be profitable tomorrow or in a year. You can only check this moment's numbers and do your calculations based on that.

Newer versions of ASICs are typically more cost efficient (using less energy to gain more hashes), but they are also more costly. It may just be most cost-efficient to buy a bit out-dated version

Furthemore, direct profitability may not be the only reason. If you have 100 of the same miner already, it's probably best to get one more instead of the newest model, for maintenance reasons.